# "Who to follow" algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, recommendation-engine, graph-algorithm

I want to give users the ability to view some personalized users they might find interesting and might follow them...

I was thinking of it like that:

```
- Get all users he is currently following
- Get all followers that they follow
- rank them by total posts they made (DESC), filled up personal information fields
- show 5 of them on each page load
```

in case user has followers then an information message will appear...

Can this kind of feature be done with this algorithm or is there a better or even easier way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your algorithm, I'm wondering why you need to sort users based on number of posts, maybe it has something to do with reputation?

Recommendation is indeed a very large, open topic, and is also a hot academic research fields. If we are working on a practical project, I think it will be nice to to stay simple and focused.

I witnessed the following two kinds of recommendations on a very popular 
social website. From my experience, the recommendation output is of high quality. Here I'm brainstorming the algorithms behind. Hope it helps.

1. Discover persons you might know: Recommend person whose 'following set' intersects with your 'following set'. It is based on the "clustering effect" of social network: The friend of your friend is more likely to be your friend.
2. Recommend person based on interests: If the users could be celebrities, companies, institutions, press media, etc., then recommendations like the following might be useful: "People following @Linus also follow @Stallman, @LinuxDeveloper, ...". Suppose you've just followed @Linus, to recommend @Stallman, @LinuxDeveloper, first we need to find out all users following @Linus, then figure out their common following list, possibly ranked by number of followers. The idea is to recommend users based on interest correlations. We calculate and discover high correlation users, assuming that users' following list are grouped by their interests.

(I'm also thinking, algorithm 1 will discover persons that share common interests with you, if users could be celebrities, etc.. This might be preferred for some scenarios.)

Answer (score 2):

You're asking a very open-ended question here - how to pick a small number of recommendations out of a large set.  So the answer is - you can make it as simple or as complicated as you want it to be!  The simplest would be to pick a few at random (and any more complex algorithm had better prove that it produces better results than that.)  Your solution of gathering all users who are two hops away, and then ranking by number of posts, is just a bit more complex, and then at the other extreme are the sophisticated algorithms used by the Amazons and Googles of the world.  Companies put a lot of effort into building this sort of thing - have you heard of the [Netflix Prize](http://www.netflixprize.com/)?

Comment: i didnt know that the way this sort of feature works was such a big deal... are out there similar algorithms doing what im looking for? what do you mean complex? for the speed of it or?

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you want to follow the user that could offer high quality information about your Thema .we need an Algorithm to give this user as result to us ,but how can I find these users:
The users that have many Followers are a good choice but not always many of users in Twitter follow another users only as respect or ethiquet.
The users that his/her twitts retwitt many times with other user is a good choice
and the user that they are mentioned many times by other users.
I think ,to find theses users we should use Link based Analyse such as HITS or Page rank algorithim

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider not including people that are following the given user. I imagine  might not be so interested in you, and this could potentially be problematic. However, you maybe very interested in finding more about the people that  is following.

Are you considering showing the user the reason why these people were recommended to them? For example, saying like you may be interested in what little billy is saying because of his connection to your wife. If so, to potentially avoid angered users, it may be worth allowing them to in a sense opt-out.

It seems like other than that, it seems like it is a pretty good way of recommending users that someone would be interested in. The only other things that I can think of that might also help find people with similar interests, is if you allow users to tag posts. Allowing you to find users by similar interests, or by what they are posting about.

One other more problematic thing that you could look into is finding users by similar interest. for example, if person a is following person c, and person b is following person c, then maybe recommend person a to person b. though this seems like it could make for some very lengthy queries if you are not careful.